# WebKit error domain and codes in iOS headers?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uiwebview, webkit

I want to trap a specific error from a UIWebView, specifically WebKitErrorFrameLoadInterruptedByPolicyChange (102) in webView:didFailLoadWithError:

The trouble is that since the WebKit framework proper isn't accessible in iOS I can't find those constants anywhere.

Is the only solution truly to hard code @"WebKitErrorDomain" and 102?

I hope not :)

Answer (score 1):

Men.. I have the same problem. It's lazy, but work

```
#define WebKitErrorFrameLoadInterruptedByPolicyChange 102
```

You can even use a enum if need more constant.